# why should i use axis 2 for jax-ws 2 compliant web service development

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws, apache-axis

based on this link http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/jaxws-guide.html 
I assume that axis 2 provides FULL support for JAX-WS 2 compliant web service development. 
My question is why should i use Axis-2 as web services runtime instead of using my app server's (like websphere's)  inbuilt support for JAX-WS web services development.

Are there any special reasons for using AXIS 2 like runtimes. My assumption is they are provided as embeddable web services runtime implementations that can be used with tomcat / resin etc. which do not provide out of box web services support. And that they are not required to be used with app servers like websphere or weblogic which already provide support for full jax-ws 2 compliant web service development out of the box.

please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely recommend using what WebSphere or any other server provides out-of-the-box whenever possible. You'll know it's tested and supported.

Somebody who really knows Axis2 may have reasons to prefer the 3rd-party version of it (WebSphere's JAX-WS support is actually based on Axis2), but I can't speak to that.